# Split database select execution in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This code works but I want to have a separate SQL execution to select the Phones and link to its corresponding person. How do I do that?

```
var persons = personsRepository.Query()
    .Select(x => new PersonDto
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Emails = x.Emails.Select(y => y.Email),
        Phones = x.Phones.Select(y => y.Number)
    }).ToList();
```

Using Include below works - two SQL queries are executed, one for person-emails join and another for person-phones, and persons end up having a list of Persons with their Emails and Phones. But I want to limit the selection of fields that I need (i.e. Email and Number). That is why I prefer using Select (projection) like the code above.

```
var persons = personsRepository.Query()
    .Include(x => x.Emails)
    .ToList();

persons = personsRepository.Query()
    .Include(x => x.Phones)
    .ToList();
```

For brevity, I am omitting about 6 other entities that will have to be Included/joined to person.

Comment: Once again use a `Select` (projection)

Comment: Why do you want separate SQL execution?  Surely it would be quicker as a single SQL operation?

Comment: @TheGeneral, that's what I was doing in the first code snippet.

Comment: @Mick, a I mentioned, there are 6 other entities that need to be joined to person. Having 7 of them joined to person performs badly. So splitting that monolithic query into 2 or 3 is what I want to try.

Comment: `personRepo.Query().Include(x=>x.Phones).Select(x=>x.Phones.XXX).ToList()` doesn't that solve the problem?

Comment: How much data are you pulling back? how many rows, do you need all this data back at once? is the data transfer really your bottle neck? also are you joining with in memory collections, or is it all DB

Comment: @TheGeneral, there will be paging applied to this, maybe 500 every page. No joining with other memory collections, all in DB. Regardless, I want to know how to split queries with projection.

Comment: @AliDoustkani, that will return a list of string (phone numbers), EF relationship fix-up will not work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably after SelectMany...

```
IList<string> emails = personsRepository
    .Query()
    .SelectMany(x => x.Emails.Select(e => e.Email))
    .ToList();

IList<string> phoneNumbers = personsRepository
    .Query()
    .SelectMany(x => x.Phones.Select(e => e.Number))
    .ToList();
```

EDIT: OK.... so what about simply...

```
var personEmails = personsRepository
    .Query()
    .Select(x => new PersonDto
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Emails = x.Emails.Select(y => y.Email),
    }).ToList();

var personPhones = personsRepository
    .Query()
    .Select(x => new PersonDto
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Phones = x.Phones.Select(y => y.Number),
    }).ToList();
```

This will result in two queries. The first a join on the Person and Email table, the second a join on the Person and Phones.  Compared to your first attempt which does a join on the Person, Email and Phone tables in a single query.

If you're wondering if there's a way of instructing EF to break up a single LINQ query into multiple SQL queries I would say there is no way to do that.

Comment: this results in persons having a list of string (Number). List of Emails in the first query is overwritten by the query for Phones.

Comment: @ermi it was a derivative of your own code.  I've updated the answer such that the values are not "overwritten"

Comment: thanks @Mick, my code returns a list of all persons with Emails and Phones attached to them. the query for Phones does not override the query for Emails (due to EF relationship fix-up). Your code returns two separate lists of Emails and Phones.

Comment: @ermi it's not clear from your question or comments what it is you're trying to do...

Comment: thanks @Mick, I updated the question. I hope it is clearer now.